# Laptop restarts after opening Games, no overheat

Tags: windows-10, laptop, freeze, reboot

I have HP pavilion dv6 7002st.

2 weeks ago I opened my laptop to clean the fan and reapply the thermal paste...
I did and it helped me a lot with my FPS (it raised fps from 40 to 70 in games)
But 2 days ago, in the middle of the game, with no overheating, laptop suddenly shut down and came back after 10 seconds with no warning or errors.

Immediately after login, PC screen started to flicker and shake and laptop froze completely.  I removed the battery and unplugged it then plugged it after 30 seconds then opened it and everything was normal till the next game play...
All of these happened again after playing the game like for 10 minutes (I'm playing World of Tanks and restart is very annoying in online games:/ )

Then I checked the Event Viewer, I saw 2 critical errors, it was Kernel Power 41(63) errors twice ( 1 for restart and 1 for screen flickering and laptop freezing after restart)

I installed BurnInTest app to test the hardware, RAM was OK, SSD was OK, but when i choose the "max CPU temp test" and starts it, laptop restarts 10 seconds after the test starts.
The maximum temperature when laptop restarted was 76°C (I think this is not a high temp to force the laptop to shut down.)

Before I cleaned my laptop it was usually around 80°C while playing games even after 3 4 hours it was fine.

I reduced the Maximum Processor State from 100% to 99% at control panel Power Options to prevent CPU overclock (this was a suggestion by a YouTube video)  and tested the max CPU temp again. After 5 second the screen flickered and laptop completely froze and I unplugged it, this time no restart happened but the error on the Event Viewer was the same as before: Kernel Power 41.
So what can I do? Replace adapter or something or this is a hardware problem?

This problem only happens while game or test program is running
Leaving laptop on for hours or browsing the web or watching videos are OK.

Specs:

- HP Pavilion DV6 laptop
- CPU: Intel Core i7 3610QM 2.30 GHz
- RAM: 8GB DDR3
- PSU: Nvidia GeForce 630M (2GB)
- SSD: Samsung EVO 850 (it's a replacement for the old HDD)
- Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: You're not clear if this problem started occurring before or after you opened the laptop? If after you opened the laptop, then clearly you have not properly serviced the laptop. It's also clear that this IS a heat problem. You likely have not properly reassembled the laptop and a component other than the CPU is overheating. It's even possible you did damage to the motherboard by improperly flexing the board and now when it heats up there is a bad connection, or possibly static electricity.

Comment: This problem started 2 weeks after i opened the laptop, first 2 weeks was fine

Comment: Maybe you are right, but why is this problem shows up after 2 weeks? Is there any chance that my Addaptor cause this problem due to the Eventviewer error report ?

Comment: The event viewer entry you mention is a standard entry whenever the laptop shuts off improperly. The operating system doesn’t know why it shut off, it simply suggests a few different items that might be the cause.

Comment: Update : Today I opened my Laptop and CPU temp was 35-40°c - I took a "max cpu temp" test with BurnInTest App, and laptop restarded after 5 min while cpu was around 55°C... - then I took 3D GPU test, after 10 minutes into test, fan speed increased and laptop started to getting hot, then after another 10 minute with the maximum fan speed, test passed !! No restars; CPU was around 87°C just when the test finished ! I let it to cool down to 70°C then started the MaxCpuTemp test again... it restarted again after 1-2 min... - so it looks like it isn't a heat problem at all...